# ParserError: Unknown string format: EM:AIL

Tags: python, pandas

I have a df with a column - queue time. It has time values. But the type of these values are str. It might also contain incorrect values like 'abc' or 'email' in it as well. The time values are of the form '10:23', '22:22', '1:1', etc.

I want to convert these values to '10:23:00', '22:22:00', '01:01:00' and so on.
If it's not a time value and is a string, I want to ignore them.

I tried to apply this :

```
df['queue time'] = pd.to_datetime(df['queue time'].str.split(':', expand=True)
                                              .apply(lambda col: col.str.zfill(2))
                                              .fillna('00')
                                              .agg(':'.join, axis=1)).dt.time
```

But it gives an error when it encounters values like 'abc' or 'email' and gives the following error :
ParserError: Unknown string format: EM:AIL

How do I tweak my code. Need some expert help. thanks!

Comment: Which pandas version do you have? Ensure using a recent version

Comment: @mozway it's 1.3.4

Comment: @ I don't think it's a pandas version problem. It's stopping on the ParseError. It's not able to zfill and fillna EM:AIL or convert it into datetime.

Comment: Can you post the full error with stack trace? Because in the title you're saying `TypeError: 'expand'`, but in the question your talking about `ParserError: Unknown string`. Which is it now?

Comment: please provide a fully reproducible example (including DataFrame constructor to reproduce the error)

Comment: @mozway I edited the question header. The exact issue is mentioned in the question description.

Comment: I just need to add a try and except block for this action. But I am unable to figure how to do so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC, just use:

```
df['queue time'] = pd.to_datetime(df['queue time'], format='%H:%M', errors='coerce').dt.time
```

output:

```
  queue time
0   10:23:00
1   22:22:00
2   01:01:00
3        NaT
```

Used input:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'queue time': ['10:23', '22:22', '1:1', 'EM:AIL']})
```

Comment: it's still giving ValueError: time data 'EM:AIL' does not match format '%H:%M' (match)
Like I have mentioned, there are incorrect values in this column too, and I want to be able to ignore such values and do not perform this function on them.

Comment: @SoumyaPandey then your column does NOT contain `'10:23'`

Comment: It does. It has both such values like '10:23' and 'Email/Slack'. I want to convert values like '10:23' to '10:23:00' and ignore values like 'Email/Slack'.

Comment: I updated the answer to handle invalid formats

Comment: @SoumyaPandey *"It does"*. Then please (as other people already mentioned) provide a fully reproducible example (including DataFrame constructor to reproduce the error) - [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 0):

Just addition @Mozway solution just pass parameter `errors='coerce'`

```
df['queue time'] = pd.to_datetime(df['queue time'], format='%H:%M',errors='coerce').dt.time
```

input

```
 queue time
0      10:23
1      22:22
2     EM:AIL
3    abv:ess
```

output

```
  queue time
0   10:23:00
1   22:22:00
2        NaT
3        NaT
```